# FloatingActionButton visible despite of ProgressBar

Tags: android, xml, layout, progress-bar, floating-action-button

I have a layout with one FAB and a custom Progressbar, all inside a CoordinatorLayout.
My Progressbar hide all layout content during data loading, but not the FAB.

I tried to move Progressbar in all position of layout but FAB is always visible.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/Recycler1"
    style="@style/MyStyle1"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/FAB1"
    style="@style/MyStyle2"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_event_black_24dp" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/Progressbar1"
    style="@style/MyStyle3" />
```

Here My Activity code

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private View view;
    private RecyclerView Recycler1;
    private ProgressBar Progressbar1;
...
    private Context context;
    private List<...> array_data;
    private RequestQueue queue;
...


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = getActivity();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
        Progressbar1 = view.findViewById(R.id.Progressbar1);
        FloatingActionButton FAB1 = view.findViewById(R.id.FAB1);
...
        Recycler1 = view.findViewById(R.id.Recycler1);
        Recycler1.setHasFixedSize(true);
        Recycler1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
...
        // Set Volley queue
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Progressbar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
getData();
    }


    private void getData() {
        array_data = new ArrayList<>();
        JsonArrayRequest jsArrRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
...
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                try {
...
                    Progressbar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() { @Override public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { ... }})
        { @Override public Map<String, String> getHeaders() { return ... } };

        queue.add(jsArrRequest);
    }
}
```

EDIT
I forgot to write that the background of my custom Progressbar is not transparent, so it automatically overlap all other items in layout.

```
<style name="MyStyle3">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_bar</item>
</style>
```

Custom Progressbar drawable:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <rotate 
            android:toDegrees="1800">
            <shape
                android:innerRadius="25dp"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thickness="4dp"
                android:useLevel="false">
                <gradient
                    android:endColor="@color/colorBlue"
                    android:startColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:type="sweep" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

I want to hide FAB when Progressbar is visible, setting the correct proprierties in layout and not doing this programmatically. Progressbar must overlap FAB.

Comment: Share your `activity` code

Comment: @JakirHossain done, now you find my code in the question.

Comment: Please share your full `my_fragment.xml` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option - 1:** You have to modify the default **Z Axis** behavior of `FloatingActionButton` by updating `elevation`.

```
app:elevation="0dp"
```

**Option - 2:** If you want to keep default behavior of FAB then you have to update your `my_fragment.xml` somethings like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/Recycler1"
            style="@style/MyStyle1"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/FAB1"
            style="@style/MyStyle2"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_event_black_24dp" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/Progressbar1"
        style="@style/MyStyle3" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This code work for me. Thanks. But I have a basic question: Why before of this solutions my Progressbar hide all other items but not the FAB? Why FAB is different from any other views ?

Comment: FAB is different from other views because of it's **Z Axis**. FAB design in such a way that it always be on top of other to serve the purpose. You can change this behavior by modifying **Z Axis** of FAB.

Comment: Please accept and upvote if it helps you so that others can find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks, you help me to understand that the difference of FAB from other views is the Z Axis behavior. The second solutions work fine for me, and I suppose can be quite. Anyway the first solution seems to not work. If I set app:elevation="0dp" for the FAB, it is always hide.

Answer (score 1):

first, hide the visibility of the progressbar

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/Progressbar1"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    style="@style/MyStyle3" />
```

after that make progressbar visible when you need to use it and hide the FAB button

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
FAB1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

you can set FAB visibility to `GONE` instead of `INVISIBLE`
the difference between `GONE` and `INVISIBLE` is

**INVISIBLE:**

> This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout
>   purposes.

**GONE:**

> This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout
>   purposes.

Comment: Hi, this solution work of course, and I already know. But I prefere to do not programmatically hide FAB, but I simply want thant when progressBar is visible this overlap FAB, like any other items in layout.

Comment: I have no idea about that if you search might be you will get it

Comment: Probably I forgot to explain some particular thing about my custom progressBar.
The background of Progressbar is not transparent but tinted of white, and take all the parent, so it cover all the others items (but not the fab) under the Progressbar. I edited my questions adding the complete code, so you can understand.

Comment: did you try to change your layout?

Comment: Previous answer of Md. Asaduzzaman work for me and is what I'm looked for. I only not understand: Why FAB is different from any other views? Why my Progressbar hide all other items but not the FAB?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method in your `activity` like `showProgress(boolean status)`

```
private void showProgress(boolean status){
  if(status){
     Progressbar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     FAB1.setVisibility(View.GONE); // decleare FAB1 globally like Progressbar1
  }else{
     Progressbar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     FAB1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
}
```

And call it when you want to show or hide your `progressbar`.

To show `progressbar` in your `onResume`

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    showProgress(true);
    getData();
}
```

To hide `progressbar` inside your `getData`

```
private void getData() {
        array_data = new ArrayList<>();
        JsonArrayRequest jsArrRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
        //...
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                try {
                    //...
                    showProgress(false); // call method here and pass false
                } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() { 
               @Override 
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { 
                   // also here you have to close your progressbar 
                   showProgress(false);
                   //...
               }
            })
        { @Override public Map<String, String> getHeaders() { return ... } };

        queue.add(jsArrRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Probably I forgot to explain some particular thing about my custom progressBar.
The background of Progressbar is not transparent but tinted of white, and take all the parent, so it cover all the others items (but not the fab) under the Progressbar. I edited my questions adding the complete code, so you can understand.
I like to hide FAB setting layout in correct way (like any others layout items), not programmatically.